# No consigo usar un WebViewClient

Tags: android-studio

Veran, tengo un programa el cual tiene que llevarme a una pagina web:
***[https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingo_(programa_de_televisión)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingo_(programa_de_televisi%C3%B3n))***

Tras añadir lo siguiente en AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Preparo el webview en un fichero xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/Paginado"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

E introduzco este código en el correspondiente fichero java:

```
package com.example.pcx.lingo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class pagina extends Activity{
    WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manual);

        browser=findViewById(R.id.Paginado);
        browser.setWebViewClient( new Control() );

        String cadena="<a href='https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingo_(programa_de_televisión)'/>";
        browser.loadData(cadena, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }

    public class Control extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView browser, String url){
            browser.loadUrl( url );
            return(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo se cuelga el programa. ¿Que falla?

Comment: Ese href sera invisible ya que no tiene ninguna etiqueta asociada

Comment: @eyllanesc Yo diria que esta asociado a la etiqueta 'a'...

Comment: Osea no se ve el texto, por lo que no se podra presionar, a eso me refiero

Comment: @eyllanesc Ahora te entiendo. Pero eso no quita que mi programa se cuelgue.